# "Voltar a repetir" vs "Repetir"

Tags: português-brasileiro

Queria saber se **"voltar a repetir"** e **"repetir"** têm o mesmo significado. Ou seja, repetir diz a mesma coisa nos seguintes exemplos?

> EX: É absolutamente necessário que não voltem a repetir os mesmo erros.

> EX: A montanha repetia os gritos de socorro.

Comment: Acho que depende da interpretação. Na minha interpretação, são diferentes. Para mim: "o Carlinhos repete os erros" diz que esse Carlinhos faz os mesmos erros mais de uma vez; "o Carlinhos volta a repetir os erros" diz que ele já repetiu os erros no passado, e agora vai repeti-los novamente. A minha conclusão é que esse Carlinhos é meio estupido.

Comment: quando for usar "voltou a repetir" dá uma ideia de algo que aconteceu no passado e agora, depois de um tempo, está acontecendo de novo. Apenas "repetir" é algo que acontece sempre e não tem parou ainda.

Comment: No primeiro examplo parece-me o mesmo sem _voltar_  (_repetir_ significa já _fazer de novo_). Mas no segundo _repetir_ significa _ecoar_, _reproduzir_, portanto _voltar a repetir_ significa _ecoar novamente_ (i.e., ecoou antes e agora tornou a fazê-lo).

Comment: Obrigado pelos explicações. Agora ficou claro. Alguem quiser deixar uma resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As duas expressões não têm necessariamente o mesmo significado.

A rigor, "voltar a fazer" é o mesmo que "fazer de novo", "repetir"; então "voltar a repetir" é uma dupla repetição:

- houve uma primeira vez no passado,
- uma primeira (ou mais de uma) repetição, também no passado,
- e agora refere-se a uma nova repetição (i.e., trata-se no mínimo da terceira instância).

Mas, de novo, isto é a rigor - muitas pessoas usam, especialmente numa expressão como "voltar a repetir os mesmos erros" com o significado de "repetir os mesmos erros", "voltar a cometer os mesmos erros".

No segundo exemplo, em que a montanha "repete os gritos", provavelmente ela reflete, ecoa o som dos gritos.